# How to ensure that a foreign key value is not repeated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am stupid about SQL so here's a trivial question.

If I have a table structure like so.

**User**:

```
Id (primary key)
```

**UserProfile**:

```
UserId (foreign key, primary key in user table)
OtherStuff
```

I have set the `UserProfile.UserId` as the foreign key linking it to the `User.Id` column.

How do I ensure that people don't enter more than one row for the same user in the `UserProfile` table?

Do I set a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `UserProfile.UserId` column? That's the only way I can think of.

Comment: It seems that you have already arrived at the correct answer. So why are you asking?

Comment: @MattBall - perhaps validation?

Comment: I didn't know if that was the right way. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Please don't close it. It might help someone like me later. Or it might help me later. I tend to forget stuff soon. If you just say yes in an answer and I'll mark it as the right one.

Comment: UNIQUE constraint is a correct solution for your particular context

Comment: ... If you're only allowing one record in that table, why isn't it part of the `User` table?  Wouldn't profile-type information usually be part of the base `User` table?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: For the purposes of categorization. A user may have many kinds of profiles, some are domain specific. For instance, he may have an insurance profile, and a medical profile, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique constraint. Also, assuming since it's an ID column you don't want to allow null values you can also modify the column to not accept nulls. You'll have to define alter the table with a NOT NULL condition on the column if you don't want to allow null values.

You can use this syntax to alter your userprofile table and add a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE userprofile
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> UNIQUE (userid);
```

If you don't want to allow null values:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] 
Alter COLUMN [Column] [Data Type] not null;
```